# How do I add a new tab, hide a tab, alter a formula and automatically rename it in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-api

I have a google sheets document that has the date as the sheet name for every day of the month.

For example, this month I have 10/1, 10/2, 10/3, 10/4, 10/5... etc and everyday I duplicate the old sheet, update the tab name for the new sheet and hide the oldest sheet.

For example, if I have tabs  10/1, 10/2, 10/3, 10/4, 10/5 -> Is there a way to add a new tab, name it 10/6 (with the same contents as 10/5) and hide 10/1?

I also have a formula. For example, in tab 10/6 I would have "=(B34+B30-'10/5'!B30)/B35" <-- all the contents are within 10/6 except for '10/5'!B30 which I need to change manually after duplicating the sheet.

So when I create 10/7 I need to go in and change the formula from '10/5' to '10/6'?

To recap:

1. I need to duplicate the most recent tab and change the tab name to today's date.
2. I need to hide the oldest tab, so in the example I would create 10/6 and hide 10/1
3. I need to change the formula to match the previous day, so for tab 10/6 I need the formula to link to 10/5

Tried this formula but it keeps labeling as total days so 10/14 -> 10/287

```
function duplicatesheet() {
  var as = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); // active spreadsheet
  var s = as.getActiveSheet(); // first sheet object
  var dateCell = "A1"; // cell containing first date
  var N = 1; // number of copies to make

  var startDate = new Date(s.getRange(dateCell).getValue()); // get the date stored in dateCell
  var day = startDate.getDate(); // extract the day
  var month = startDate.getMonth(); // extract the month
  var year = startDate.getFullYear(); // extract the year

  // loop over N times
  for (var i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    var asn = s.copyTo(as); // make a duplicate of the first sheet
    var thisSheetDate = new Date(year, month, day+(i+1)); // store the new date as a variable temporarily

    asn.getRange(dateCell).setValue(thisSheetDate); // writes the date in cell "B3"
    asn.setName(Utilities.formatDate(thisSheetDate, "GMT", "MM/DD")); // sets the name of the new sheet
  }
}
```

Comment: The answer is yes to all of your questions.

Comment: Most of the methods you need will be found [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet) or [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range) or [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet)

Comment: I see you have changed the question.

Comment: English isn't my first language. Just trying to be more accurate with what I am asking.

Comment: Well first you were asking if it's possible and now you are asking how to do it.  And it would be better to focus in on one thing at a time.

Comment: Yes sorry. I should have asked for "how" instead of "if". I will definitely remember for next time.

Comment: Any below I have a function that will calculated the next month and day  from the current sheets in a spreadsheet that match having 1 or 2 digits then a forward slash and then 1 or 2 digits.

Answer (score 0):

This will insert a new sheet with the correct name assuming that you are still making your sheet as 10/10,10/11,10/12,10/13 then this function will determine the proper month and day for the next sheet.

```
function insertnewsheet() {
  //find the sheets
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const shts = ss.getSheets().filter(sh => sh.getName().match(/\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}/g));
  let oA = shts.map(sh => [sh.getName()]);
  //Sort them based upon date value in milliseconds
  oA.sort((a, b) => {
    let tA = a[0].split('/');
    let vA = new Date(new Date().getFullYear(), parseInt(tA[0]) -1 , parseInt(tA[1])).valueOf()
    let tB = b[0].split('/');
    let vB = new Date(new Date().getFullYear(),parseInt(tB[0]) - 1,  parseInt(tB[1])).valueOf();
    return vA - vB;
  });
  Logger.log(oA.join('\n'));
  //take the last one and figure out the next month and day using the Date() object
  let md = oA[oA.length - 1][0].split('/');
  let dt = new Date(new Date().getFullYear(), parseInt(md[0]) - 1, parseInt(md[1]) + 1);
  let name = `${dt.getMonth() + 1}/${dt.getDate()}`;
  ss.insertSheet(name);
  Logger.log(name);
}
```